Is it possible to deploy to a specific path in firebase hosting without overwriting the root site?
I would like to deploy to a specific part of the site, for example: "site.com/other", and by doing so, not interfering with the root part already in place: "site.com/".
If possible to achieve, I would very much like to know how.
I have attempted to alter the firebase.json file on order to handle redirecting. It is as follows.
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/dashboard/**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }],


What you're trying to do is not possible.  You can only deploy an entire site at a time using the CLI.
